# Flex app does not ask to use camera in browser

Tags: apache-flex, flash-media-server

I am building a Flex 4.1 app built into a Flash 10.0 SWF.

When I run the app outside a browser, it asks for the camera and mic no problem, but once it is run in any browser, it never asks.

I'm certain it is not because the cam is being used by something else because someone else is having the same problem on their computer.

Anyone have any ideas what might cause a problem like this?

take care,
lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the 'wmmode' setting. The script I just copy and pasted from another project had it set to 'direct'. Once it is changed to 'opaque', everything worked fine.

thanks.

lee

Answer (score 0):

In system camera detect only one time. You cant access this in second time  If you allow camera earlier in flash player or browser. 
When you run application  close all other apps attached with camera.

Comment: 'You cant access this in second time If you allow camera earlier in flash player or browser', actually, this is not exactly so. You can close the browser tab, open a new one and connect the camera again in the separate instance.

Comment: Are you sure camera is not open in any other software ?

Comment: Yes, I was sure of that because it did not work after a reboot and the same problem was on a second computer. But, as you can see, I found the problem was the wmode setting.